# Checkbox not showing once checked on our website

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox

I am trying to get the checked checkbox to show up on our website. If you go to this page and choose a pricing plan: https://www.shiftdivorceguide.com/submit-listing/ then scroll to the bottom of the next page we have two check boxes, "I agree" and "Already have an account".

**When I check them they disappear and I want them to show with a check mark in them.**

HTML for I agree checkbox

```
<div class="checkbox form-group col-md-4 check_policy termpolicy">
    <input id="policycheck" type="checkbox" name="policycheck" value="true">
        <label for="policycheck">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.shiftdivorceguide.com/terms-and-conditions/" class="help">I Agree</a>
        </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
.checkbox label:before { /*This is the css code for the existing checkbox*/
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 3px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease;
    transition: all 0.1s ease;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

If I change this to to `display:inline` a second smaller box displays and if I check it on I Agree it jumps to the right. When I check the box the `:Before` instance disappears in the code along with the box on the screen

**I would like the nicer larger box (not the smaller box) to remain and show as checked when someone checks it.**

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add some code here? You can add `html` `css` code in your questions, which can show actual bug.

Comment: I can't see those check boxes as you said at bottom of that page! please add a demo page with minimum code to describe the problem

Comment: I added more code and directions on how to get to the page in question to my post above.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood you want to hide the first checkbox when clicked and the second one to remain. If that's what you want here is a potential solution to your problem:

HTML

```
<form onSubmit="yourSubmitFunction()">
  <div id="policycheck">
    <input type="checkbox" name="policycheck" value="PolicyCheck" onclick="hidePolicyCheckbox()"> I agree
  </div>
  <div id="existingAccount">
    <input type="checkbox" name="alreadyHaveAnAccount" value="alreadyHaveAnAccount"> Already have an account
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and JavaScript

```
function hidePolicyCheckbox() {
  var policyCheckbox = document.getElementById("policycheck");
  if (policyCheckbox.checked === true){
    policyCheckbox.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    policyCheckbox.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

If you want your second checkbox not to move up when the first one disappear you can use `policyCheckbox.style.visibility = "hidden";` instead of `policyCheckbox.style.display = "none";`

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually, I would like to checkbox that exists to stay as it is but just show a check mark in it when it is check. It currently dissappears. If that can't be done we can hide the existing checkbox and add the standard checkbox in. This code is in a plugin in a theme so it is not easy to access and edit.